# Using spring boot with angular for login page using spring security

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a login and welcome page using Angular as the front end and spring boot as the controller .

In my WebSecuirtyConfigureAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/src/assets/logo.png").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/main.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/main.js.map").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/polyfills.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/polyfills.js.map").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/styles.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/styles.js.map").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vendor.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vendor.js.map").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/runtime.js.map").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/runtime.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/logo.png").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/userinfo").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/#/login").permitAll()
            .successHandler(this.successHandler)
            .failureHandler(this.failureHandler)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.entryPoint)
        .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/url5/**")
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(this.csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

I need to re-direct any unauthenticated requests to authenticationEntryPoint but since I had to add "/" to allow Angular to work it is not working as expected .
As "/" is permitted every request is permitted and I do not hit the entryPoint which directs me to the login page at /#/login.
If I remove the "/" I am able to hit the entryPoint but Angular wouldn't render as spring security would not allow that to load . I need my unauthorized request to go via the entry point as this is a legacy code and it works the parameters which might be sent along with the request.
Can you please help me how to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Controller` which will forward to `index.html`.

```
@Controller
public class UiController {

    @RequestMapping({
            "/",
            "/login", //my login page is on /login
    })
    public String handler() {
        return "forward:index.html";
    }
```